# Flipped keyframes - weird result (walk cycle)

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I'm working on walk cycle animation for a rigged character and I have a problem.

If I copy keyframes of the pose I made, and duplicate flipped keyframes via Ctrl+C -> Ctrl+Shift+V - I get a weird result, the legs are pointed to wrong directions and so on.

Why could it happen and how can I fix it?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I believe that is the feature that allows you to copy keyframes and reverse the transformations of bones. Not sure exactly how it works but I use it for walk cycle. It reverses the initial pose of the character to form the middle pose of a walk cycle

Comment: Thank you, yes, that's how it should work. I'm trying to understand why it works badly in my case. I think it may be related to bones "roll" or maybe I should apply rotation position and scale for the model first. I'm trying to figure it out now.

Comment: Am thinking maybe it has something to do with mirroring the character, I don't think it would work for asymmetric meshes or bone.

Comment: use the comment section for comments, dont post answers.